# PHP MYSQL filling an array with variables and change the field names

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL. I need to fill an array and I want to change the field names and I can't achieve it.

My code:

```
$querystr = "SELECT DISTINCT descr_bien,ubicacion,marca,modelo,ano,DescrMoneda,valor    FROM bienes,Moneda WHERE bienes.IdMoneda = Moneda.IdMoneda AND bienes.Idpropuesta = '" . addslashes($Idpropuesta) . "'";
$result3 = mysql_query($querystr,$dbConn);

while($hrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)){ 
  $descr_bien = $grow['descr_bien'];
  $ubicacion = $grow['ubicacion'];
  $marca = $grow['marca'];
  $modelo = $grow['modelo'];
  $ano = $grow['ano'];
  $DescrMoneda = $grow['DescrMoneda'];
  $valor = number_format($grow['valor'],2,",",".");

$data = array(array('Descripción'=>$descr_bien,'ubicacion'=>$ubicacion,'marca'=>$marca,'modelo'=>$modelo,'Año'=>$ano,'DescrMoneda'=>$DescrMoneda,'valor'=>$valor),array($hrow));

}   
$pdf->ezTable($data,$cols,'Bienes:',array('gridlines'=> EZ_GRIDLINE_DEFAULT,'shadeHeadingCol'=>array(0.6,0.6,0.5),'showBgCol'=>1,'width'=>500,'cols'=>array('valor'=>array('justification'=>'right'))));
```

Comment: Are you wanting to change the field names in the database or the array keys?

Comment: I want to change the names of the array, Rachael, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first of all I am going to assume you have managed to set up $dcConn to get your database connection.  If not go look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Next your while statement is storing each value in $hrow but you seem to be assigning everything to grow.

Your next issue is that $data will be overwritten for every row in your result.

From what I understand you will be wanting something along the lines of

```
$querystr = "SELECT DISTINCT descr_bien,ubicacion,marca,modelo,ano,DescrMoneda,valor       FROM bienes,Moneda WHERE bienes.IdMoneda = Moneda.IdMoneda AND bienes.Idpropuesta = '" . addslashes($Idpropuesta) . "'";
$result3 = mysql_query($querystr,$dbConn);

while($hrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)){ 
  $descr_bien = $hrow['descr_bien'];
  $ubicacion = $hrow['ubicacion'];
  $marca = $hrow['marca'];
  $modelo = $hrow['modelo'];
  $ano = $hrow['ano'];
  $DescrMoneda = $hrow['DescrMoneda'];
  $valor = number_format($grow['valor'],2,",",".");

  $data[] = array('Descripción'=>$descr_bien,'ubicacion'=>$ubicacion,'marca'=>$marca,'modelo'=>$modelo,'Año'=>$ano,'DescrMoneda'=>$DescrMoneda,'valor'=>$valor));

}
```

I do not know about the last line at all so left it out.

One other suggestion that using the PDO library to access the mysql database would usually be a better idea unless this all that the php will ever need to do.

I hope this helps